# Can the Fast Fourier transform be used to compute the magnitude of moiré

Tags: image-processing, fft

I am experimenting with image down-sampling and would like to calculate a *numerical magnitude* for alias-induced moiré patterns.  Is it possible to do this by analyzing the frequency-domain (FFT) of the input image and knowing the relative sampling rate?

Assume that I have already applied any pre-sample filtering prior to taking the FFT, so the sampling will be point-based.

Comment: Do you have any sample images handy?

Comment: @Phonon: Something like the ["rings image"](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/rings_sm_orig.gif) ([large](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/rings_lg_orig.png)) in the ["Resampling Filters" article](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/) at imagemagick.org would be a good start, but I would like this to apply to any image.

Comment: I wonder if the reason I have no answers is because this question is too easy, ... or too hard. :)

Comment: Idea: Compare FFT of an aliased image to that of a reference image.  The relative magnitude of frequencies in the aliased image compared to the  same frequencies in the reference image represent the magnitude of moire at the corresponding frequencies.